# Force line break (<br/>) in header (<h1>) in Markdown

Tags: html, header, markdown, line-breaks

I'm trying to create a two-line `<h1>` in Markdown, something along the lines of:

```
<h1>Title<br/>byline</h1>
```

The Markdown docs say:

> When you do want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.

Unfortunately, this only seems to work for paragraphs -- if I try it with an `<h1>` (dots · indicate spaces):

```
#·Title··
byline
```

the trailing spaces are ignored and I just get:

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<p>byline</p>
```

Can anyone tell me a workaround for this?

P.S. I'm using vanilla Markdown 1.0.1 from the command line.

Comment: I use kramdown, which is a superset of Markdown. Two spaces at the end of a line converts to a `<br />`.

Comment: Using `pandoc` I put backslash \ at the end of the line and I've got desired result, but this is not handled correctly by `github`

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28895263/2657549)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Turns out the answer is just "use `<br/>`."

```
# Title <br/> byline
```

produces

```html
<h1>Title <br/> byline</h1>
```

** **facepalm** **

Comment: This did not work for me using `pandoc` to output to PDF. [Issue 289](https://code.google.com/p/pandoc/issues/detail?id=289) mentions it as well.

Comment: @user29020 Have you looked at the pandoc `escaped_line_breaks` extension?

Comment: **✔** Works here on **StackExchange**, awesome!

Answer (score 5):

Just use the alternative syntax for `<h1>`:

```
Title··
byline
========
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also do `double space` at the end of the line.
For example, this text appears in the same line even though I've written it on the next line.
This appears on a new line.

The thing is there are 2 blank spaces after `next line..`. (Consider those two dots as spaces)

Hope this helps. This also seems better than `</BR>`.

Reference: http://markdown-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html

Comment: As you see in the question, I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Note that it's `<BR/>` (XML self-closing tag)  and _not_ `</BR>`.