# How to Write Multiple Authors in Markdown (Pandoc)

Tags: latex, pandoc, author

I want to write a markdown file containing **multiple authors**, then convert it into a **LaTeX** and **Doc** file using **Pandoc**.

Based on the answers to [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730982/force-line-break-br-in-header-h1-in-markdown), I tried to write:

```
% Author <br/> Another Author
```

Pandoc can convert that into **two lines** in HTML files, but only **one line** (one author) in LaTeX and Doc files.

Answer (score 9):

You can supply pandoc with multiple author names using a YAML front matter section in your markdown.

For example:

```
---
author:
- "Alice Ceila"
- "Edy Jo" 
---
```