# How can I force a line break in rmarkdown's title?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a quite long title in a rmarkdown document and I would like to force a line break in a specific position.

Minimum example:

```
---
title: "Quite long title want the * line break at the asterisk"
output: html_document
---
```

I have tried: \n, \newline, \\ and a manual line break. None of them seem to work.

I believe it has to be quite straightforward but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try using a pipe `|` in each line:

```
---
title: |
  | Veryyyyyyy  
  | yyyyyyyyyyyyyy Looooo  
  | oooooooooooooooo
  | oooooooooooong 

author: "Foo Bar"
date: "6 March 2015"
output: html_document
---
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm.
Thanks

Comment: Note that the 4 spaces before the pipe and the single space after pipe are essential!

Comment: 2 spaces before the pipe (as in the code above) works too

Comment: Two spaces before the pipe, one after, with no quotation marks, works now for me.

Comment: Any idea why this works in output styles pdf_document and html_document but not word_document? Any way to achieve the same thing with a word doc?

Comment: First, thanks a lot! It worked for me but using the pipe just in the first line. For each line break, I added two spaces at the end but not any pipe character.

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: Just tried it again after 7.5 years and it still works on my Mac at least.

Answer (score 23):

For a centered, multi-line title:

```
---
title: |
  <center> Veryyyyyyy </center>
  <center> yyyyyyyyyyyyyy Looooo </center>
  <center> oooooooooooooooo </center>
  <center> oooooooooooong </center>

author: "Foo Bar"
date: "6 March 2015"
output: html_document
---
```

[image]

Comment: How does this work for beamer rmarkdown titles? I get an error when I try it

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old post, but I wanted to chime in with:

```
# A Title of some kind
<br><br><br><br><br>  

# Another title that has 5 blank lines above it
```

Note that you need 2 spaces on line 3 or the title will not display properly in Rmarkdown::html_document. This solution is a little hard to find, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

i cannot comment on the chosen answer. The preferred solution makes a warning appear as it creates a table inside the title. A correct approach for multiline titles should be the following:

```
---
title: |
    Quite long title want the
    line break at the asterisk

output: html_document
---
```