# Insert a linebreak in title

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How do I insert a linebreak in the title of an rmarkdown document?
This does not work:

```
---
title: "title \break subtitle"
output: pdf_document 
---`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force a line break in rmarkdown's title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895109/how-can-i-force-a-line-break-in-rmarkdowns-title)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use pipes

> The pipe symbol at the end of a line in YAML signifies that any indented text that follows should be interpreted as a multi-line scalar value.  See [the YAML spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688).
>
> Specifically, the pipe indicates that (except for the indentation) the scalar value should be interpreted literally in such a way that preserves newlines.  Conversely, the `>` character indicates that multi-line "folded" scalar follows, meaning that newlines are converted to spaces.

[what is the use of pipe symbol in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540635/what-is-the-use-of-pipe-symbol-in-yaml/18708156#18708156)

```
---
title: |
    | title 
    | subtitle
output: pdf_document 
---
```

[image]

This is a duplicate but I can't find the original.

edit: here it is!

[How can I force a line break in rmarkdown's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895109/how-can-i-force-a-line-break-in-rmarkdowns-title)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Care to explain why pipe is working/what exactly it's doing? Is the pipe YAML syntax?  Why doesn't \\ or \break work?

Comment: This appears to work in html and pdf output styles but not "word_document" - any idea why and how to coerce the same in a word document?

Comment: @enRANDOMSTRING [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41004076/4137985) works for me with word_document