# Split the title onto multiple lines?

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio, markdown, r-markdown

In an R markdown document (html and presentations), is it possible to manually split the title onto multiple lines? I tried playing with pipes which produces orrendous output.

```
---
title:  'A title I want to split on two lines'
author: 
date: 
output:
  ioslides_presentation
---
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For an HTML output just us the `<br>` tag while if your output is a PDF or PDF presentation standard LaTeX code to break line given by `\\` should work.

#### Example

```
---
title:  'A title I want to <br> split on two lines'
author: 
date: 
output:
  ioslides_presentation
---
```

#### For PDF

Just to rule out possibilities, I've tried to put `\\` or `\newline`, both do not split, so for PDF seems to be a little bit tricky. `\linebreak` stop knitr parsing. Maybe another user can solve this question for knitr PDFs.

Comment: does not work for flexdashboard output

Answer (score 29):

Examples for adding an abtract show the use of pipes | to break lines and include paragraphs. This works as well for the title and other yaml elements. For an abstract or title:

```
---
abstract: |
    What works for the abstract.

    Works for the title, too!
title: |
    | title 
    | subtitle
output: pdf_document 
---
```

Comment: Fwiw, OP already mentioned trying pipes, which indeed do not work for ioslides_presentation as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is **THE** correct solution!! Also recommended for all other fields, e.g. author. You can compile in all formats, unlike the other suggestions...

Comment: does not work for html_output

Answer (score 25):

For PDF output, experimentation revealed that the following works:

```
---
title:  'A title I want to  \nsplit on two lines'
author: 
date: 
output: pdf_document
---
```

That is two spaces followed by `\n`.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for the `bookdown::pdf_document2` document type for me.

Comment: Works with `word_document` and `bookdown::word_document2` too

Comment: Does not work for me. I am using output:
  beamer_presentation:

Comment: This solution did not work for `word_document` and `bookdown::word_document2` in the year 2023. The solution that did work I got from this link: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502581/multi-line-titles-with-pandoc).

Answer (score -2):

Use `\\linebreak` for pdf output.