# Include an extra section of text/hyperlink in YAML-Header section of Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I'm writing a document in RMarkdown and have hopefully a fairly straightforward query about including extra information in the header section.

My Header section of the rmd looks like:

```
---
title: "My R-Markdown Document"

author: "[My name here](a hyperlink to my institutional page)"

output: html_document
---
```

I'm trying to add a simple extra line after my name which includes my Twitter handle

I tried cheating by adding it as an abstract....:

```
---
    title: "My R-Markdown Document"

    author: "[My name here](a hyperlink to my institutional page)"

    abstract: "[I'm on Twitter](hyperlink)"

    output: html_document
    ---
```

But that displays the heading Abstract before the extra information i.e I get

"Abstract: I'm on Twitter"

Whereas the desired output would be

Title Text

Name (Hyperlink)

I'm on Twitter (Hyperlink)

Anyone know how to get this to work?
I've looked at [PANDOC Guide](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-set-by-pandoc) and other examples and I've tried all sorts of things calling it description, institute but none of these seem to render except for Abstract which has the issue highlighted above.

NB: Modified-extra query
This works for an HTML output but doesn't seem to if output == PDF
Any suggestions in that realm also welcomed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to render the RMarkdown YAML header content for a single field on multiple lines. The following examples work for me in both pdf and html formats:

**Using two spaces followed by \n**

```
---
title: "My R-Markdown Document"
author: "[My name here](a hyperlink to my institutional page)  \n[I'm on Twitter](hyperlink)"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---
```

**Using the `|` operator**

```
---
title: "My R-Markdown Document"
author: |
  | [My name here](a hyperlink to my institutional page)
  | [I'm on Twitter](hyperlink)
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---
```

**Using html line break `<br>` (works for html, not pdf)**

```
---
title: "My R-Markdown Document"
author: "[My name here](a hyperlink to my institutional page)<br><br>[I'm on Twitter](hyperlink)"
output: html_document
---
```

Note, including additional information like this in the author field may not be ideal as the additional information will also be included in the rendered html author metadata:

`<meta name="author" content="My name here  I’m on Twitter" />`

These questions might also be helpful:

[In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines)

[Split the title onto multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537515/split-the-title-onto-multiple-lines)

Comment: Great thanks. Do you know how to get same to work for a PDF output (the above doesn't seem to). M

Comment: @mmarks, I've added a couple more examples which should also work in PDF as well...