# How to prevent hyphenation of long headings in R Markdown?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

I have a few long headings in R Markdown.
Some of them end up with a word split across lines by a hyphen when knitted to pdf.

Is there a way to prevent this?

I'm guessing standard markdown would have a similar issue?

Comment: Is "cut the headings short" not an option?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

It seems there is way to push words in the next line in titles of R Markdown files (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559106/split-title-in-two-lines-in-rmarkdown-for-word-output/51570546), but I haven't found anything for headings yet

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52193443/2425163 One can pass raw pandoc options via the `pandoc_args` YAML array.

Comment: r-markdown uses pandoc, which in turn uses LaTeX for PDF creation. You can pass along LaTeX instructions in `includes: header`...