# rmarkdown to preserve line breaks in YAML header variable during export

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I am exporting an `rmarkdown` file to `odt`, to `html`, and to `pdf`.  But let's focus on the `odt` export first.

I want to have an address as part of the YAML header:

```
---
title: Test Multi
address:
  First Name
  Institute
  Street
  City
output:
  odt_document:
    template: default.opendocument
---

# Just a test document
With some text
```

This address should then be exported as part of the 'header'.  Therefore, I have added the following snippet into the [default odt-template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.opendocument) (saved as `default.opendocument`):

```
$if(address)$
<text:p text:style-name="Author">$address$</text:p>
$endif$
```

But at the export the line breaks are lost:

[image]

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41444545/1844418) I tried pipes as in

```
---
title: Test Multi
address: |
  | First Name
  | Institute
  | Street
  | City
output:
  odt_document:
    template: default.opendocument
---

# Just a test document
With some text
```

But then, the address is missing completely from the odt.

So, my question is:  How can I have the multi-line address from the YAML added to the export preserving the line breaks?

PS: I am using `rmarkdown 1.12` and `pandoc-2.7.3`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on.

1. As you discovered, you need `address: |` for YAML to not gobble up your line-breaks.
2. But the string is treated by pandoc as markdown and [pandoc's markdown by default](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-hard_line_breaks) treats linebreaks inside a paragraph as spaces. But you can escape them:

```
address: |
  First Name \
  Institute \
  Street \
  City
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  Does not fix it for me, though:  The address in the exported odt is still missing.

Comment: Ok, I found it.  I am not allowed to style this as it will be styled for me and I am ending up with nested `<p>`.  If I replace `<text:p text:style-name="Author">$address$</text:p>` by `$address$` this works with your syntax in the `Rmd`.