# How can I force a line break in rmarkdown's title for ioslides presentation?

Tags: r, r-markdown

The solution for [`html_document`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28895263/2591234) output does not work for `ioslides_presentation` output. How can I force a title change at a specific location?

The solution for `html_document` output produces very strange results.

```
---
title: | 
  | This is an extremely long title
  | with a desired line break at a 
  | specific location
output: ioslides_presentation
---
```

Answer (score 10):

Well, I just figured it out myself. You can add `html` tags to the title, e.g. `<br>`. This works:

```
---
title: This is an extremely long <br> title with a <br> desired 
  line break <br> at a specific <br> location
output: ioslides_presentation
---
```

Comment: I think that is a possibile duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537515/split-the-title-onto-multiple-lines/30537573#30537573