# How add a blank line between title and authors in YAML output - Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I have a code like this in rmarkdown:

```
---
title: "title"
author: "author"
output: pdf_document
---
```

How can i add a empty line between the title and author? In default output the author's name is very close to title's name. I think that solution is simple, but i can't see it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Following [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28895263/3174566), you can add multiple lines to the title or the author using the | symbol.

```
---
title: "title"
author: |
   | 
   | author
output: pdf_document
---
```