# Line break in title of Rpres

Tags: html, css, r, markdown, rpres

I am crafting my presentations as `.Rpres` as of lately. My title is a little long and breaks at an arbitrary location. Is there a way to influence this behavior? I tried HTML (`<br>`) and  `|` but no success... It sounds so elementary, but I did not find any info here or on Google.

```
Is there a way to display the heading in two lines?
========================================================
```

It should look kind of like this:

```
Is there a way to display 
the heading in two lines?
========================================================
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: .Rpres compiles to markdown, so using two space characters before the line break should work. (It does here on SO in editor preview, but not for the rendered result - but I think that might be a SO problem?)

Comment: @CBroe thanks a lot. I tried that but for me it didn't work. apparently the whole title has to be in one single line

Comment: Looks like it might be deliberate that they did not make this work in headlines, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730982/force-line-break-br-in-header-h1-in-markdown

Comment: You said in comments, using HTML would not work for you - not even when it is _just_ the `<br>`? You should be able to keep the _rest_ of the syntax as you have it, i.e. generate the headline via the `=====` underneath, you would not have to write the actual `<h3>` / `</h3>` tags as HTML as well.

Comment: No, that just gives me `long title <br> in two lines`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<pre>Is there a way to display 
the heading in two lines?</pre>

<p>Is there a way to display<br> the heading in two lines?</p>
```

Comment: Hi thanks but .Rpres are Markdown documents that might accept HTML, but your solution does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `html` than `<br>` tag will break the text to next line

```html
<h3>Is there a way to display<br>
the heading in two lines?</h3>
```

Comment: Hi thanks but .Rpres are Markdown documents that might accept HTML, but your solution does not work for me